# JRadioButton values to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

```
// radio action listener
            ActionListener radioListener = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    text.setText(e.getActionCommand());


                }
                };

                // motherboard group
                 rb1.addActionListener(radioListener);
                 rb2.addActionListener(radioListener);
                 rb3.addActionListener(radioListener);
                 // cpu group
                 rb4.addActionListener(radioListener);
                 rb5.addActionListener(radioListener);
                 rb6.addActionListener(radioListener);
```

i need some help, when i click JRadioButton group, the value of the JRadioButton group to be display in the JTextArea, for each selected group. i am getting one group at a time now.
thanks

Comment: The value of the group or the value of selected `JRadioButton` from the group ?

Answer (score 0):

You override the textarea each time when one radio button event is thrown.
Try to use JTextAre.append() instead of setText.

In any case you have to remember any kind of state of the radio button groups within you ActionListener to reach the expected behaviour.

Update due to comment:

This is not completely correct. I didnt' check it. But it shows the main aspects.
At first its better to implements the listener interface by a concrete class and not
kust to pass it as an anonoumys type. In this case the class RadioButton implements the actionListener Method. Now your are able to pass any kind of argument or object reference to the listener class. Annd you can use it within you listener method.

Further look at how i get the Source of the event. This is done via

```
JRadioButton source = (JRadioButton)e.getSource();
```

If you assign a name or an id to the radiobutton you can check for that name and react
in the appropriate way.

Here the example code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class RadioButton implements ActionListener {


boolean group1Clicked = false;
boolean group2Clicked = false;

JRadioButton rb1 = new JRadioButton();
 ...
JTextArea text = new JTextArea();

public RadioButton() {
      rb1.addActionListener(this);

      rb2.addActionListener(this);
      rb3.addActionListener(this);
      ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
      rb1.setName("rb1");
      rb2.setName("rb2");
      // cpu group
      rb4.addActionListener(this);
      rb5.addActionListener(this);
      rb6.addActionListener(this);  
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  JRadioButton source = (JRadioButton)e.getSource();

  if (source.getName().equals("rb1") ||
      source.getName().equals("rb2") ||
      source.getName().equals("rb3"))  {
      //Changing the state
      if (group1Clicked) {
          group2Clicked = false;
      } else {
          group1Clicked = true;
      }
  }

  if (source.getName().equals("rb4") ||
          source.getName().equals("rb5") ||
          source.getName().equals("rb6"))  {
          //Changing the state
          if (group2Clicked) {
              group1Clicked = false;
          } else {
              group2Clicked = true;
          }
      }

  if (group1Clicked==false || group2Clicked ==false) {
       text.clear();
    } else {
       text.append(e.getActionCommand());
    }


}
```

};

Comment: but now every selection i make is appended to the text area. what i need is when i make a selection, only that selection appended to the text area and next one so on.

Comment: yeah thats the problem. So you need to remember the states. You need to check if both radio groups where already selected before. If so you must clear the text area.

Comment: could you please help me and give example how would i do that.

Comment: could you please help me, an example how to implement how to check the state of each group